# How to create an Google Sheets arrayformula which contains ranges

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have the following formula which I need to convert to an arrayformula.
`=IF(AND(E2>0,F2>0,E2<>"",F2<>""),A2,"")`

I have tried the following but I can't get it to work.
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="","",IF(AND(E2:E>0,F2:F>0,E2:E<>"",F2:F<>""),A2:A,"")` but this is returning empty values when it shouldn't

I have also tried this
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="","",IF(AND(E2:E,">0",F2:F,">0",E2:E,"<>""",F2:F,"<>"""),A2:A,"")` but it won't work as well

I'm missing something. If this requires a sample google sheets then I can provide. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayFormula does not support `AND`. try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((E2:E>0)*(F2:F>0)*(E2:E<>"")*(F2:F<>""), A2:A, ))
```

or perhaps:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D<>"", IF((E2:E>0)*(F2:F>0)*(E2:E<>"")*(F2:F<>""), A2:A, ), ))
```